# C# Extracting an XML data with public DTD

Tags: c#

The XML file is created with a public DTD. The XML can have different locations therefore when i'm going to read the XML file, i get an error like "Couldn't find dtd file". DTD path set in XML is dependent on the XML location and it's not ideal to create a DTD file in w/c the XML files are located.

So i'm thinking to create a copy of an XML file with a new DTD declaration where the DTD path is set to my local directory where the DTD is located but i don't know how and i'm not sure if this would fix my problem. I'm currently using XmlDocument to extract some XMl data.

I tried searching a solution online but i couldn't find any to solve my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this have to work:

```
    private string msValidationError;
    public string validateXML(XmlTextReader reader, string sDTDPath)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings oSettings = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
        oSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
        oSettings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallBack;
        System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(sDTDPath); //Set dtd folder             

        System.Xml.XmlReader oReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(reader, oSettings);
        try
        {
            msValidationError = "";
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
            }
            oReader.Close();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msValidationError))
            {
                return string.Format("Invalid xml! {0}",msValidationError);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Invalid xml.";
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                oReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exI)
            {                    
            }
        }
        return msValidationError;
    }

    private void ValidationCallBack(object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs args)
    {   
        msValidationError = msValidationError + args.Message;
    }
```